# (Core Data) How to make a random sorting for NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to get objects from database in random order.
First, I generate random "id"s into `NSArray` and set them as predicate:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.id IN %@)", randomIds];
// The example of randomIds contents (always different):
// <__NSArrayM 0xd1cc4e0>   (185,51,69,25,33,135,136,97,157,112,145,132,56,15,159,70,88,6,72,82)
```

But to this time my results are still sorted because `NSFetchedResultsController` insists on setting the "sortDescriptors" for its `FetchRequest`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortingDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortingDescriptor];
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

But I need the fetch results in random order: the same as in "randomIds" array.

I haven't found any reasonable solution for this problem yet. How would you solve it? Is there a chance someone already has come to any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest creating an NSSortDescriptor that uses a comparator block, and have that block use a random number generator to decide which item goes first for each comparison.

However, I have a vague memory that you can't use comparator-based sort descriptors in fetch requests to Core Data when the internal database is SQLite.

Why don't you simply convert your fetched results array into a mutable array and then scramble them:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) scrambledArray: (NSArray *) theArray
{
  NSMutableArray *result = [theArray mutableCopy];
  NSUInteger count = [result count];
  for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; index++)
  {
    NSUInteger random = arc4random_uniform(count);
    id itemAtIndex = result[index];
    result[index] = result[random];
    result[random] = result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The code above is very fast, taking O(n) time to complete.

Comment: Already tried a comparator block - yes, it's forbidden to be used with Core Data, unfortunately. Of course I can easily shuffle the elements of the resulting array into another array, but I use `NSFetchedResultsController` object in `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (I really need it this way)

Answer (score 0):

If you never need the sort descriptor, just delete it from the fetched results controller.

If you need it only sometimes with the same fetched results controller, you have to reinitialize it. Just keep a flag around and reload the fetched results controller.

```
if (!useRandom) {
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptor = ...;
}
else {
   // add the predicate
}
```

To reload without this sort descriptor, just do this:

```
useRandom = YES;
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.tableView reload Data];
```